# Where to #include headers?

Tags: c++, header, include, libraries

I looked up header file examples, but could only find simple ones with nothing to include.

So my question is where do I `#include` stuff like `string` and `vector`? In the .h or the .cpp file? Or maybe in both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anywhere you need.

If you need something declared in a header file, include them in the .h file.
Otherwise just in the .cpp file.

Note that including a .h file is just a textual replacement and the contents of the included .h file will be entirely inserted <strike>at the beginning of the file where they've been included.</strike> at the precise point of the `#include` line.
It is good practice to include a project-belonging headers before the standard library ones and never include a header if you don't need it.

Last thing you should keep in mind is that when working with **large projects** including many headers in a .h file shared by many translation units can increase compilation times if the header gets modified. It's usually preferred to just include what you strictly require in the appropriate files (either .cpp or .h). Precompiled headers might also help but it's off-topic to your question.

Finally: don't rely on "this header has been included somewhere else and I'm already including it through a second header" because it could render dependencies-tracking hard and favor circular dependencies when the project grows.

Comment: Addition, to enforce proper inclusion as much as possible: Always include the header belonging to an implementation-file first.

Comment: @Deduplicator Right you are. I generally take this even further, "sorting" the includes by generality: file itself first, other files from my project next, then specific 3rd party libraries, then broad 3rd party libraries (e.g. Qt), then Boost, and standard library last.

Comment: Two comments: first, I've usually seen the reverse order for inclusion (except for the header of the implementation file, which is always first): standard library and system headers, then external libraries and finally other libraries in your program.  (I don't know why, however.  I can't think of any real reason to prefer one order over the other.)  And second, there is usually one exception to not relying on includes in the header: the implementation file is permitted to depend on includes in its own header.

Comment: "... the contents of the included .h file will be entirely inserted at the beginning of the file where they've been included." This is misleading. They will be included at the exact point in the file where the `#include` directive is found, not at the beginning. Meaning, if you write the `#include` at the last line of a file, the contents of the included file will be inserted at the end of the including file.

Comment: @ArneMertz: You're right; I've updated the answer. It matters to the question _where_ to include the header.

Comment: Thanks both of you for editing the answer, I had to leave the pc for a while :)

Answer (score 2):

> where do I #include stuff like string and vector? In the .h or the .cpp file?

There are multiple issues to consider in this, especially when projects get bigger (i.e. the bigger your project is, the more this affects you).

Personally, I follow these rules:

- if code needs a header to compile, then you need to include it (if header declares things with std::string in the API, you will have to include `string` and the same goes for the C++ file)
- do not include headers that are not needed (i.e. not "both" - if you include a header in your .h file, then include your .h file, you should be fine).
- organize headers prioritizing for your project's files. this means if you have in a C++ file local project headers, and std and boost headers, you should (probably) include local project headers first, then boost, then std.

  This is because the std headers will be the most tested/stable ones, and the most used API (this is a blind supposition on my part). If you were to include std headers first, and then project headers (for example), since the replacement is textual, you could get away with not adding the include in the project header. This would basically mask an error, because you would end up having to include the std headers before the local project header in all other cpp files from now on.